# "Prove me" / "prove to me" / "confirm one's belief"

Tags: grammar

Which sentence do you find more natural?

> Your last actions only prove me that you're not worth my trust.
>
> Your last actions only prove **to** me that you're not worth my trust.

or maybe some other form like

> Your last actions only confirm (my belief / me in the belief) that you're not worth my trust.

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second sentence, 'prove to me', is more natural (and indeed correct where the first one is not). Prove is a verb so needs the **to**.

The 'confirm my belief' (me in the belief isn't quite right) sentence is a bit formal.

Comment: The last form would be good for emphasis, IMO.

Comment: It's nothing to do with whether "prove" is a verb. See Hellion's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The verb *prove* is never used with an indirect object, only a prepositional object.

You can use indirect object with verbs of communication and and giving, such as

> He asked me a question.  She gave me a dirty look.

But you would never say

> He proved me an equation.  She proved the company her value.

The correct form for that is always "proved (direct object) to (prepositional object)", as in

> He proved an equation to me.  She proved her value to the company.

The only case where you would find a personal noun or pronoun directly after "proved" is when you are using that personal reference as a shortcut to mean something that this person has said (and therefore they are the direct object of *proved*):

> Prove me wrong, if you can.
>   The course of events proved him correct.

Comment: Re the last point: no it's not necessarily about what the person said. It is "Prove [a person] [a description]" meaning "Prove that [the person] is [description]". So "Prove me a liar!" "This proved him unfit for office". The description is generally a negative one.

Answer (score 0):

My preference goes to

> Your last actions only confirm (my belief / me in the belief) that you're not worth my trust.

but "prove to me" would also be correct.

Note: I suspect you mean "worthy of my trust" rather than "worth of my trust". (worthy = deserving, worth = important/valuable enough)